# Android : Set fontFamily in TextAppearance not working

Tags: android, styles, themes

I wanted to have a default Headline TextStyle with fonts, and every style(HeaderStyle, HeaderTwoStyle) inheriting should be able to display correct font, in case I wanted to override the font in Headline. But its not working...

```
<style name="Headline1" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/font_28sp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/headline1</item>
</style>

<style name="HeaderStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/Headline1</item>
</style>

<style name="HeaderTwoStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/Headline1</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write like `<style name="HeadLine1.HeaderStyle">` to override style in the same file